# How to validate Sub-Sets of JSON Keys using match contains when there are nested JSON's in the response

Tags: json, karate

From a response, I extracted a subset like this.

```
{
  "base": {
    "first": {
      "code": "1",
      "description": "Its First"
    },
    "second": {
      "code": "2",
      "description": "Its Second"
    },
    "default": {
      "last": {
        "code": "last",
        "description": "No"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If I need to do a single validation using **And match X contains** to check

1. Inside first the Code is 1
2. Inside default-last the code is last?

Instead of using json path for every validation, I am trying to extract a specific portion and validate it. If there is no nested json paths, I can do it very easily using **And match X contains**, however when there are nested jsons, I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
* def first = get[0] response..first
* match first.code == '1'
* def last = get[0] response..default.last
* match last.code == 'last'
```

Edit: ok looks like you want to condense into one line as far as possible, more importantly to be able to do `contains` in nested nodes. Personally, I find this sometimes to be not worth the trouble, but here goes.

Refer also to these short-cuts: https://github.com/intuit/karate#contains-short-cuts

```
* def first = { code: "1" }
* match response.base.first contains first
* match response.base contains { first: '#(^first)' }
* def last = { code: 'last' }
* match response.base contains { first: '#(^first)', default: { last: '#(^last)' } }
```

Answer (score 1):

Mhmm, My question is slightly different I think.
For example if I directly point to the **first** using a json path and save it to a variable savedResponse, I can do this validation

```
And match savedResponse contains {code: "1"}
```

If there were 10 Key value combinations under **first** and if I need to validate 6 of those, I can use the same json path and I can easily do it using match contains

Similiar way if I save the above response to a variable savedResponse, how I can validate mutliple things using match contains, in this. The below statement will not work anyway.

```
And match savedResponse contains {first:{code:"1"}, last:{code:"last"}}
```

However if I modify something will it work?

Comment: edited my answer, I think this is what you are looking for ?